# Network interfaces for Jails

Tags: networking, freebsd, jails

I have been reading over the creation of Jails on FreeBSD, and one stumbling block I have is regarding network interfaces.

Say my local router is 10.0.2.1, and the BSD box is 10.0.2.5. I would like jails on 10.0.2.6-10.

Do I just define them in `rc.conf` (without any other work), or do I have to set up a bridge or something like that (I see FreeNAS uses a bridge)?

I'm not particularly strong the networking side of things, so any good explanation about how the Jails share and access the network would be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jails get ip aliases on your network interface. If the jails use the same interface as the host and are on the same subnet you don't need to do any additional routing.

If your jails do not use the same interface you would need to bridge the primary interface with the interface the Jails use.